# Optimisation of nonlinear matrix objective with semidefinite constraints (classical Fisher information)

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, positive-semidefinite, fisher-information, schur-complement, schur-decomposition

Given the invertible *symmetric* block diagonal matrices $S = S_1\oplus S_2$ and $dS = dS_1 \oplus dS_2$, I want to
find the symmetric matrix X with blocks
$$
X = \left[ 
\begin{array}[cc]
~X_1 & X_{12}\\
X_{12}^T & X_2
\end{array}
\right]
$$
that maximises the following objective (which is related to the Fisher information of a Gaussian distribution, if you are familiar with that)
$$
F = {\rm trace} [(dS(X+S)^{-1})^2],
$$
subject to
$$
X + i\Omega \succcurlyeq 0, {\hspace .2cm }\text{with  } \Omega = \omega\oplus\omega, {\hspace .2cm} \text{and   } 
\omega = \left[ 
\begin{array}[cc]
~0 & 1\\
-1 & 0
\end{array}
\right].
$$
The known matrix $S$ also satisfies this same criterion, i.e., $S+i\Omega \succcurlyeq 0$. For our purpose, we can also assume $S_i$ and $dS_i$ are diagonal for $i \in \{1,2\}$.

I think in general this can be a difficult optimisation problem. I have the conjecture that the optimal $X$ should have off-diagonal blocks vanish, i.e., $X_{12}^{\rm opt} = 0$.
Unfortunately, I am stock in the matrix inversion and I cannot prove this. I would appreciate it if anyone can give me some hint. Alternatively, if one could give a counter example for which the optimal $X_{12}^{\rm opt}\neq 0$ it would be great.